# Looking for a way to create a batch of realm that points to the same home server pool in the proxy

Tags: proxy, freeradius, radius

I'm looking for the method to have a group of multiple users (realm) to be proxied to a specific radius server.

Example in the proxy.conf:

```
realm a 
        auth_pool = radius_server_pool1

realm b
        auth_pool = radius_server_pool1

realm c
        auth_pool = radius_server_pool1
etc...
```

What if I have over 100 users, is there a more efficient way to do it? I know that we can add @ to the username and have the proxy strip it but unfortunately it's not an option for now.

Thank you

I tried to create each realm manually but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do it.